# Bashscript: read a certain, multi-line tag from XML-file and parse attributes

Tags: xml, bash

I have to read specific tag attributes from an XML-file and return them to a Template-Document.
I've finished *reading* the file itself, now how can I read one tag only and parse its attributes?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<instances
name="instance-name"
port="60535"
username="bar"
password="foo"
string_var="barfoo">
some xml (up to 5k lines and 3 k elements i do not need)
</instances>
```

How can I read the string until I encounter the ">" for instances? And how can I put the values into variables?

Wanted output:

```
TPAR_PORT = 60535
TPAR_USERNAME = bar
TPAR_PASSWORD = foo
TPAR_INSTANCE = instance-name
```

By the way it does not matter if the values are with or without single quotes

Comment: possible duplication: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4680143/how-to-parse-xml-using-shellscript

Comment: problem is where to start and if the lines are separate as with kate or gedit, or if its one line as in normal opening. also i only need the attributes from the instances tag. some xml can be up to 5k lines of xml and i don't wanna select parser output...

Comment: Show some code. Show your expected output. Try xmlstarlet, Nokogiri, or some some other XML parser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a proper XML parser. You example is not a well-formed XML, though: `foo` and `bar` are not allowed in the XML declaration, which must end in `?>`, not a simple `>`. Also, `encoding` should be used instead of `charset`.

After fixing the file, you can start using the proper tools.

```
<?xml version="1.0" charset="UTF-8"?>
<instances
name="instance-name"
port="60535"
username="bar"
password="foo"
string_var="barfoo">
some xml
</instances>
```

For example, you can use `xmllint` and its `--shell` option:

```
$ xmllint 1.xml --shell  <<<'cat /instances/@port'
/ > cat /instances/@port
 -------
 port="60535"
/ >
```

My favourite tool is [xsh](http://p3rl.org/XML%3a%3aXSH2):

```
$ xsh <<<'open 1.xml ; echo /instances/@port'
60535
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this

```sh
while read
do
  eval $REPLY 2>/dev/null
done < a.xml
```