# Replace a value in XML

Tags: linux, awk, sed

I have a xml tag like below:

```
<Setting Name="Check" Type="xsd:integer">53</Setting>
```

I need to fetch only 53 with the best possible code. Can someone suggest?

I know it can be achieved as below:

```
grep "Setting Name=\"Check\"" abc-test.xml | cut -d'>'  -f 2 |  cut -d'<' -f 1
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With only `grep` command

```
grep -oP '(?<=>).*?(?=</Setting>)' input.xml
```

For extending conditions(**i.e.:** Check) you can mention elements too like this,

```
grep "Name=\"Check\"" input.xml|grep -oP '(?<=>).*?(?=</Setting>)'
```

The **output** will be,

```
53
```

Here is what I tried,

[image]

Comment: This is a great command.. Thank you. But problem am facing now is that the above grep is displaying many lines which ends with </Setting>.

Is it possible to please explain the above command?

In fact I want to select only line <Setting Name="Check" Type="xsd:integer">53</Setting>

Comment: @user1677102 good to know it solved your problem, hope you don't mind accepting this as answer.

Comment: Sure, by all means am accepting this answer :)

Answer (score 4):

I will always suggest an `xml` parser for this kind of task, like [xmlstarlet](/questions/tagged/xmlstarlet) and using `xpath` expressions. An example:

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -v '/Setting[@Name="Check"]/text()' abc-test.xml
```

that yields:

```
53
```

---

**UPDATE** with [xmllint](/questions/tagged/xmllint) version:

```
xmllint --xpath '/Setting[@Name="Check"]/text()' abc-test.xml
```

Comment: But, xmlstarlet  is not available on the linux host that am using at all.. Please let me know for any other way

Comment: You can also use `xmllint`, replacing the binary and its arguments but the xpath expression and the input file. But I'm not going to be trying until can find one of your toolbox. It's better you to visit this [how to parse xml from shell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4680143/how-to-parse-xml-using-shellscript) and choose one.

Comment: I see in my host --xpath for xmllint is not supported..I get the Usage listed

Unknown option --xpath
Usage : xmllint [options] XMLfiles ...

Comment: How to replace the value with something else with xmllint?

Answer (score 3):

Possible codes are as follows..I don't know if this is the "best" for you.

**using sed**

```
sed '/Setting Name="Check"/{s/^[^>]\+>\([0-9]\+\)<.*/\1/g}'
```

**example**

```
echo '<Setting Name="Check" Type="xsd:integer">53</Setting>'|sed '/Setting Name="Check"/{s/^[^>]\+>\([0-9]\+\)<.*/\1/g}'
```

**using awk**

```
   awk -v FS="<[^0-9]+>" '$0~"Setting Name=\"Check\""{print $2}'
```

**example**

```
echo '<Setting Name="Check" Type="xsd:integer">53</Setting>'|awk -v FS="<[^0-9]+>" '$0~"Setting Name=\"Check\""{print $2}'
```