# Unix script extract from XML and create a new XML file

Tags: xml, unix

I have a double mission with some XML files, which is pretty challenging for my actual beginner UNIX knowledge. I need to extract some strings from multiple XML files and create a new XML file with the searched strings..

The original XML files contain the source code for creating PDF files. I write here an abstract example and explain after the challenge.

```
<Header>My favorite restaurant</Header>
 <breakfast_menu>
  <food>
  <name>Belgian Waffles</name>
  <price>$5.95</price>
  <description>Two of our famous Belgian Waffles with plenty of real maple   syrup</description>
  <calories>650</calories>
  </food>
  <food>
  <name>Strawberry Belgian Waffles</name>
  <price>$7.95</price>
  <description>Light Belgian waffles covered with strawberries and whipped cream</description>
  <calories>900</calories>
  </food>
  <food>
  <name>Berry-Berry American Pie</name>
  <price>$8.95</price>
  <description>Light American Pie covered with an assortment of fresh berries and whipped cream</description>
  <calories>900</calories>
  </food>
  <food>
  <name>French Toast</name>
  <price>$4.50</price>
  <description>Thick slices made from our homemade sourdough bread</description>
  <calories>600</calories></food><food><name>Homestyle Breakfast</name>
  <price>$6.95</price>
  <description>Two eggs, bacon or sausage, toast, and our ever-popular hash browns</description>
  <calories>950</calories>
  </food>
 </breakfast_menu>
<Footer>My favorite restaurant</Footer>
```

So, the UNIX script should extract the Header, the entire rows that contain 'Belgian' and 'American' and the Footer and put them in a new XML file. The list with the searched strings is provided through a separate Input file. I hope I managed to create a clear requirement. Please let me know if any extra information is needed.

Thank you very much,
Milano

Comment: About how a xml file can be parse with a script see a related question like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4680143/how-to-parse-xml-using-shellscript.

Comment: Thank you for the link! I need a direct script in Unix to run automatically on a Unix machine.