# Retrieve elements from Mailchimp archive RSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, rss

I'm trying to extract the titles and descriptions from the MailChimp RSS feed using jQuery.

I'm trying with:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'http://us10.campaign-archive1.com/feed?u=21a65076da97205b5e5ff33e6&id=cc8bfc765e',
    crossDomain: true,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function (xml) {
        $(xml).find("item").each(function () {
            var title = $(this).find("title").text();
            var description = $(this).find("description").text();
            var linkUrl = $(this).find("link_url").text();
            var link = "<a href='" + linkUrl + "' target='_blank'>Read More<a>";
            $('#feedContainer').append('<article><h3>' + title + '</h3><p>' + description + link + '</p>');
        });
    }
});
```

But I get the error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < on
http://us10.campaign-archive1.com/feed?u=21a65076da97205b5e5ff33e6&id=cc8bfc765e&callback=jQuery214010618008393794298_1436280190025&_=1436280190026
```

If it's not possible through jQuery, is there another method? I tried with Yahoo Developer Console but robots.txt disallows the access..

It seems mailchimp disallow access that doesn't come from browsers, I tried to curl the URL and I get a 404 not found.

Answer (score 2):

1. You need to parse XML before query with jquery (https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML)

   ```
   var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(xml);
   var $xml = $(xmlDoc);
   $xml.find("item");
   ```
2. Set valid dataType to `xml`

Answer (score 2):

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < on
>       http://us10.campaign-archive1.com/feed?u=21a65076da97205b5e5ff33e6&id=cc8bfc765e&callback=jQuery214010618008393794298_1436280190025&_=1436280190026

The above error is caused by the fact that JSONP requires the returned data to be valid JSON/javascript, which XML is not.

Unfortunately JSONP is needed in your case as CORS isn't enabled on this specific server. (see [CORS for Apache](http://enable-cors.org/server_apache.html))

The result is that you cannot use jQuery only if the returned data can be changed to JSON.

I just tried `curl`, and it seems to work fine, no 404 error for me, maybe you need to use a proxy? And make sure your quote the url, as the character `&` is handled specially in a shell.

```
curl 'http://us10.campaign-archive1.com/feed?u=21a65076da97205b5e5ff33e6&id=cc8bfc765e'
```

And if you're going to use curl, there would be more than one options to parse xml, such as xmllint, see [How to parse XML using shellscript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4680143/how-to-parse-xml-using-shellscript)

Here's an example using `xmllint`:

```
xmllint --nocdata --xpath '//item[1]/title/text()' <(curl -s \
  'http://us10.campaign-archive1.com/feed?u=21a65076da97205b5e5ff33e6&id=cc8bfc765e')
```

It prints the first title:

```
AVVIO ANNO SCOLASTICO 2015/2016
```