# sed regex inside xml tags

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I'm trying to clean up some XML with `sed`. I've got a big XML file with lots off data including address details.  The address details are within the `<line>` tag. For some reason the system has `<REAR` (yes, without the last '>') `<FRONT>` `<REAR>` littered inside.

For example:

```
<Address>
<line>123 & GRD FLOOR <REAR</line><line>59 EXAMPLE RD</line>    <line>CITY</line><line></line><line></line><line>RG1 1AB</line>
</Address>

<Address>
<line>SECOND GRD FLOOR <FRONT></line><line>59 EXAMPLE RD</line><line>CITY</line><line></line><line></line><line>RG1 1AB</line>
</Address>

<Address>
<line>123 & GRD <REAR> FLOOR</line><line>59 EXAMPLE RD</line><line>CITY</line><line></line><line></line><line>RG1 1AB</line>
</Address>
```

I've been told to just escape the information so, here are a change of `sed` commands I'd like to apply within the line tags.

```
sed 's/ *$//g'; 's/ *#//g'; 's/&/&amp;/g'; 's/</&lt;/g';'s/>/&gt;/g'
```

Any help much appreciated, this is doing my head in.

EDIT: Forgot to say that the tags can appear else where outside of `<line>`. These need to stay intact.

EDIT2: Sorry, I should have said that this running on a customer Unix system. So installing 3rd party tools isn't really an option.

Comment: In most cases, you shouldn't use regex to pars HTML/XML. You'd be better off using a dedicated xml parser

Answer (score 3):

Usually, regular expressions aren't strong enough to parse XML (or HTML). The problem is, that HTML/XML are more complex than regular expressions (as in different levels in [Chomsky hierarchy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chomsky_hierarchy)).

For this task, you should use a more sophisticated tool - such as [lxml](http://lxml.de/) or [beautifulsoup4](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) with Python.

Further reading on the topic:

- [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)
- [How to parse XML in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/893585/how-to-parse-xml-in-bash)
- [How to parse XML using shellscript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4680143/how-to-parse-xml-using-shellscript)
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_grammar
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_grammar