# How to edit xml resource array by shell script in which integer values are divided by 1.5

Tags: xml, shell

i used some point in array like this

```
<array name="placeholderBucket">
    <item>0</item>
    <item>20</item>
    <item>276</item>
    <item>150</item>
    <item>522</item>
    <item>150</item>
    <item>848</item>
    <item>20</item>
    <item>0</item>
    <item>600</item>
    <item>848</item>
    <item>220</item>
</array>
```

//i want to get these point divide by 1.5 like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <array name="placeholderBucket">
        <item>0</item>
        <item>13</item>
        <item>184</item>
        <item>100</item>
</resources>
```

actually i have lots of arrays for changing the original points into points which is divide by 1.5

Comment: parse xml file read each value and rewrite back to file.

Answer (score 0):

parse XML file read each value and rewrite back to file.for reading xml file from shell script refer [How to parse XML using shellscript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4680143/how-to-parse-xml-using-shellscript)