# BASH: Find a string in file after finding a first string

Tags: bash, sed

Please bear with me...

I have a large xml file, I need to find a string "JOBNAME=9027" then find the line that comes after it that contains "TASKTYPE" and change that line.

So I have to change the TASKTYPE line that comes after JOBNAME=9027.  There are several hundred JOBNAME and TASKTYPE lines, all different amounts of lines away from each other.

I have tried sed, awk and bash to no avail.  I am sure there is a way to do it, but it is escaping me.

EXAMPLE:

```
JOBNAME="MYSAP#SDOR-SG-D-LATECODED-0927"
            JUL="1"
            JUN="1"
            MAR="1"
            MAXDAYS="0"
            MAXRERUN="0"
            MAXRUNS="0"
            MAXWAIT="0"
            MAY="1"
            MULTY_AGENT="N"
            NODEID="sappr2"
            NOV="1"
            OCT="1"
            PARENT_FOLDER="MYSAP#SSDOR-D-SG-LATECODED-0927"
            PRIORITY="10"
            RETRO="0"
            RULE_BASED_CALENDAR_RELATIONSHIP="O"
            RUN_AS="MYSAP"
            SEP="1"
            SHIFT="Ignore Job"
            SHIFTNUM="+00"
            SUB_APPLICATION="MYSAP"
            SYSDB="0"
            TASKTYPE="Job"
```

Comment: Give an example chunk and your desired output from that..

Comment: Here goes a chunk, remember there will be multiples of similar data.

Comment: It keeps telling me the text I enter is too long.

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/893585/how-to-parse-xml-in-bash or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4680143/how-to-parse-xml-using-shellscript

Comment: Please [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/37557924/edit) and the chuck on the question..

Comment: done, sorry, obviously new here.

Comment: The file snippet you entered is not XML... I assume it is a part of the actual XML with all lines you entered are just attributes of the same node. Anyway... for parsing xml, you should use tools like `xmllint` or `xmlstarlet`; not `awk`/`sed`...

Answer (score 7):

#### Using sed

Try:

```
sed '/JOBNAME.*0927/,/TASKTYPE/ {s/TASKTYPE.*/TASKTYPE="NewJob"/}' largefile
```

This produces as output:

```
JOBNAME="MYSAP#SDOR-SG-D-LATECODED-0927"
            JUL="1"
            JUN="1"
            MAR="1"
            MAXDAYS="0"
            MAXRERUN="0"
            MAXRUNS="0"
            MAXWAIT="0"
            MAY="1"
            MULTY_AGENT="N"
            NODEID="sappr2"
            NOV="1"
            OCT="1"
            PARENT_FOLDER="MYSAP#SSDOR-D-SG-LATECODED-0927"
            PRIORITY="10"
            RETRO="0"
            RULE_BASED_CALENDAR_RELATIONSHIP="O"
            RUN_AS="MYSAP"
            SEP="1"
            SHIFT="Ignore Job"
            SHIFTNUM="+00"
            SUB_APPLICATION="MYSAP"
            SYSDB="0"
            TASKTYPE="NewJob"
```

How it works:

- `/JOBNAME.*0927/,/TASKTYPE/ {...}` executes the commands in curly braces **only** for groups of lines that start with a line matching the regex `JOBNAME.*0927` and end with the first line after that that matches `TASKTYPE`.
- `s/TASKTYPE.*/TASKTYPE="NewJob"/` replaces the `TASKTYPE` followed by anything with `TASKTYPE="NewJob"`.

#### Using awk

This awk script uses the same logic:

```
awk '/JOBNAME.*0927/,/TASKTYPE/ {sub(/TASKTYPE.*/, "TASKTYPE=\"NewJob\"")} 1' largefile
```

How it works:

- `/JOBNAME.*0927/,/TASKTYPE/ {...}`

  This executes the commands in curly braces **only** for groups of lines that start with a line matching the regex `JOBNAME.*0927` and end with the first line after that that matches `TASKTYPE`.
- `sub(/TASKTYPE.*/, "TASKTYPE=\"NewJob\"")`

  This performs the substitution.
- `1`

  Unlike sed, awk does not, by default, print anything.  This `1` is awk's cryptic shorthand for print-the-whole-line.

  In more detail, `1` is a logical condition.  It evaluates to "true."  We specified no action to go along with that condition.  Therefore, awk performs its default action which is print-the-line: `print $0`.

Comment: That seems to work, can you give me a little explanation of the code so I may learn?

Comment: @Vonedaddy I just added some explanation.

Comment: One last comment,  what is the "1" for at the end of the line?

Comment: @Vonedaddy I have added an explanation for the lone `1` also.