# Get a tag value in multi line XML using shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a xml file as follows

```
<Module dataPath="/abc/def/xyz" handler="DataRegistry" id="id1" path="test.so"/>
<Module id="id2" path="/my/file/path">
  <Config>
    <Source cutoffpackage="1" dailyStart="20060819" dataPath="/abc/def/xyz" />
    <Source cutoffpackage="1" dailyStart="20060819" dataPath="/abc/def/xyz" id="V2"/>
  </Config>
</Module>
```

I just want to extract value of `dataPath` from every `moduleid`.

I was using, the command like

```
`grep 'id2' file | grep -ioPm1 "(?<=DataPath=)[^ ]+"`
```

which is giving me from the first module id, not for second module id. because second module is in multiple lines.

How can i do this using shell script?

Desired output would be– if i want to get the datapath of id1 module, then is should get

```
/my/file/path
```

Of for second module id, say id2, i should get datapath separated by comma

```
/my/file/path, /my/file/path
```

Or my second approach to grep the datapath is to replace the `newline character` between `<Module` and `</Module>` only, then i can use grep.

Comment: [You can't parse \[X\]HTML with regex](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3776858)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse XML in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/893585/608639), [How to parse XML using shellscript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4680143/608639), etc

Comment: @jww, no it's not. i have edited the questions to get better understanding

Comment: Your desired output shows two lines. The 1st line has the value of 1 `dataPath` attribute, and the 2nd line has the value of 2 `dataPath` attributes - each separated by a comma. Presumably that structure indicates a pattern relating to your source xml? Does each newline equate to a `<Module>` element node? i.e the 1st line indicates there is a `<Module>` with 1 associated `dataPath` attribute, and the 2nd line indicates there is 2 `dataPath` attributes associated with another `<Module>`.  Presumably a list of all matching values, one value per line, is not what you want. Please clarify in OP.

Comment: @RobC, i have a configuration file, which is having configuration of each `module` (Known by id). Some of the `modules` have their complete information in a line, and some `module` have their information in multiple lines. I just need to extract one tag `datapath` for every `module`. This may possible that one moduleid may have multiple `datapath`

Answer (score 2):

`-m1` tells grep to exit after first matching line, that's why it prints only one line of output.
I wouldn't use a line oriented tool for this though. There are more convenient tools out there for parsing XML, such as [xmlstarlet](/questions/tagged/xmlstarlet):

```
xml sel -t -m '//@dataPath' -v . -n file.xml
```

Comment: or `xml sel -t -v '//@dataPath' -n file.xml`

Comment: @Cyrus that'd print a blank line if there were no elements with `dataPath` attribute.

Comment: In this case, yes. You can also omit `-n` if you don't need the final line break.

Comment: This prints each matching attribute value on a separate line. However,, I'm pretty sure the OP wants to group values per line, i.e. print all `dataPath` attribute values associated with a `Module` element node, (including those associated with descendant nodes) and delimit them with a comma. A newline (to my understanding) should act as a delimiter for each `Module` element node.

Answer (score 1):

*Firstly my answer assumes that you have actual well formed source XML. The example code you've provided doesn't have a root element - but I'll assume there is one anyway.*

Bash features by themselves are not very well suited parsing XML.

This renowned [Bash FAQ](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/113) states the following:

> **Do not** attempt [to extract data from an XML file] with [sed](/questions/tagged/sed), [awk](/questions/tagged/awk), [grep](/questions/tagged/grep), and so on (it leads to [undesired results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454))

If you must use a shell script then utilize an XML specific command line tool, such as [XMLStarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/docs.php) or [xsltproc](http://xmlsoft.org/XSLT/xsltproc.html). Refer to the download info [here](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/download.php) for XML Starlet if you don't have it installed already.

---

### Solution:

1. Given your source XML and your desired output consider utilizing the following [xslt](/questions/tagged/xslt) template to achieve this.

   **template.xsl**

   ```xml
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
     <xsl:output method="text"/>

     <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:template>

     <xsl:template match="Module">
       <xsl:choose>

         <xsl:when test="@dataPath and not(descendant::*/@dataPath)">
           <xsl:value-of select="@dataPath"/>
           <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
         </xsl:when>

         <xsl:when test="not(@dataPath) and descendant::*/@dataPath">
           <xsl:for-each select="descendant::*/@dataPath">
             <xsl:value-of select="."/>
             <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">
               <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
             </xsl:if>
           </xsl:for-each>
           <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
         </xsl:when>

         <xsl:when test="@dataPath and descendant::*/@dataPath">
           <xsl:value-of select="@dataPath"/>
           <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
           <xsl:for-each select="descendant::*/@dataPath">
             <xsl:value-of select="."/>
             <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">
               <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
             </xsl:if>
           </xsl:for-each>
           <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
         </xsl:when>

       </xsl:choose>
     </xsl:template>

   </xsl:stylesheet>
   ```
2. Then run either;

   - the following XML Starlet command:

     ```
     $ xml tr /path/to/template.xsl /path/to/input.xml
     ```
   - Or the following `xsltproc` command:

     ```
     $ xsltproc /path/to/template.xsl /path/to/input.xml
     ```

   <sub>**Note:** The pathnames to `template.xsl` and `input.xml` in the aforementioned command(s) should be redefined to wherever those files reside.</sub>

   Either of the commands above essentially transform your `input.xml` file and print the desired results.

---

### Demo:

1. Using the following `input.xml` file:

   ```xml
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <root>
     <Module dataPath="/abc/def/1" handler="DataRegistry" id="id1" path="test.so"/>

     <Module id="id2" path="/my/file/path">
       <Config>
         <Source cutoffpackage="1" dailyStart="20060819" dataPath="/abc/def/2" />
         <Source cutoffpackage="1" dailyStart="20060819" dataPath="/abc/def/3" id="V2"/>
       </Config>
     </Module>

     <Module id="id3" path="/my/file/path" dataPath="/abc/def/4">
       <Config>
         <Source cutoffpackage="1" dailyStart="20060819" dataPath="/abc/def/5" />
         <Source cutoffpackage="1" dailyStart="20060819" dataPath="/abc/def/6" id="V2"/>
       </Config>
     </Module>

     <Module id="id4" path="/my/file/path" dataPath="/abc/def/7"/>
     <Module id="id5" path="/my/file/path" dataPath="/abc/def/8"/>


     <!-- The following <Module>'s have no associated `dataPath` attribute -->
     <Module id="id6">
       <Config>
         <Source cutoffpackage="1" dailyStart="20060819" id="V2"/>
       </Config>
     </Module>

     <Module id="id7"/>
   </root>
   ```
2. Then running either of the aforementioned commands prints the following result:

   ```
   /abc/def/1
   /abc/def/2, /abc/def/3
   /abc/def/4, /abc/def/5, /abc/def/6
   /abc/def/7
   /abc/def/8
   ```

---

### Additional Note:

If you wanted to avoid the use of a separate `.xsl` file you could inline the aforementioned XSLT template in your shell script as follows:

**script.sh**

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

xslt() {
cat <<EOX
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Module">
    <xsl:choose>

      <xsl:when test="@dataPath and not(descendant::*/@dataPath)">
        <xsl:value-of select="@dataPath"/>
        <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
      </xsl:when>

      <xsl:when test="not(@dataPath) and descendant::*/@dataPath">
        <xsl:for-each select="descendant::*/@dataPath">
          <xsl:value-of select="."/>
          <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">
            <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
          </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
      </xsl:when>

      <xsl:when test="@dataPath and descendant::*/@dataPath">
        <xsl:value-of select="@dataPath"/>
        <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
        <xsl:for-each select="descendant::*/@dataPath">
          <xsl:value-of select="."/>
          <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">
            <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
          </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
      </xsl:when>

    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
EOX
}

# 1. Using XML Startlet
xml tr <(xslt) /path/to/input.xml

# 2. Or using xsltproc
xsltproc <(xslt) - </path/to/input.xml
```

<sub>**Note:** The pathname to your `input.xml`, (i.e. the `/path/to/input.xml` part in `script.sh` above), should again be redefined to wherever that file resides.</sub>