# How to split an log file with 4 xml nodes into 4 files using Bash?

Tags: xml, linux, bash, awk

I need to split an XML file with 4 nodes into 4 files. Given a file like this:

```xml
sddskjdsfds
asdadsa
20:15:12 st: <aRoot>
   <aNode>v</aNode>
   <otherNode a="2"/>
</aRoot>
kjfsdfj
20:15:59 r: <otherRoot>
   <bNode>h</bNode>
</otherRoot>
sddskjdsfds
asdadsa
22:31:32 st: <aRoot>
   <aNode>a</aNode>
   <otherNode a="1"/>
</aRoot>
kjfsdfj
22:31:39 r: <otherRoot>
   <bNode>o</bNode>
</otherRoot>
other-random-lines
```

I need to split it into 4 files: *`aRoot_1.xml`, `aRoot_2.xml`, `otherRoot_1.xml`, `otherRoot_2.xml`.

So far I've achieved:

```bash
awk '/st:/,/<\/aRoot>/' file.txt > all_aRoots.txt
```

And similar aproach for `<otherRoot>`: another call to `awk`, writing to `all_otherRoots.txt`, etc.

But that keeps all the chars before `</aroot>`, and results in all the `<aRoot>` being in the `outputfile`.

How do I split an log file with 4 xml nodes into 4 files using Bash?
**UPDATE #1**:
Please mind the non-xml lines, they must be excluded, and, if possible, from the lines with XML starting with non-xml text must keep only the XML part

**UPDATE #2**:
A sample output file from RavinderSingh13 answer:

```
sddskjdsfds
asdadsa
20:15:12 st: <aRoot>
   <aNode>v</aNode>
   <otherNode a="2"/>
```

Comment: Use the right tool for the job. [How to parse XML in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/893585/608639), [How to parse XML using shellscript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4680143/608639), etc.

Comment: @jww The input file IS NOT an XML file; is a log file with a lot of different XMLs besides other non-XML lines, as the example I gave

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you please try following.

```
awk -F"[><]" '
/^<\//{
  out_file=ind"_"array[ind]".xml"
  print val > (out_file)
  close(out_file)
  val=ind=""
}
/^[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]/{
  ind=$(NF-1)
  array[$(NF-1)]++
}
{
  val=(val?val ORS:"")$0
}
'  Input_file
```

---

---

EDIT: Adding code to remove starting non-desirable lines by OP.

```
awk -F"[><]" '
/^<\//{
  out_file=ind"_"array[ind]".xml"
  flag=1
  if(val){
    print val > (out_file)
  }
  close(out_file)
  val=ind=""
}
/^[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]/{
  ind=$(NF-1)
  array[$(NF-1)]++
}
flag{
  val=(val?val ORS:"")$0
}
'  Input_file
```

Comment: Thanks for your update, it didn't work (created just 3 files, 1 for aRoot, 2 for otherRoot); I'll change my approach and stop trying a one-liner solution