# Insert content of file at specific line number of another file in LINUX/BASH

Tags: linux, shell

---

I have two following files - 'tempFile' and 'File1'

### tempFile

```
tempFile 01
tempFile 02
tempFile 03
tempFile 03
```

### File1

```
File1
 @type ABCDF #---Insert 'tempfile' content below First occurrence '@type ABCDF'
File2
File3
 @type ABCDF
File4
 @type ABCDF
File5
```

I tried to insert content of  'tempFile' to another file 'File1' at first occurrence of statement '@type ABCD' with following script

```
lineNumber=$(grep -n -m 1 '@type ABCD' File1 | awk -F':'  '{print $1}' | head -1)
sed -i "${lineNumber}r tempFile" File1
```

However, the above script inserted content of tempFile in File1 multiple times as mentioned below
Please help me to insert content of tempFile in File1 only once/
Script generates following output

```
File1
 @type ABCDF #---Insert 'tempfile' content below First occurrence '@type ABCDF'
 tempFile 01
 tempFile 02
 tempFile 03
 tempFile 03

 tempFile 01
 tempFile 02
 tempFile 03
 tempFile 03

 tempFile 01
 tempFile 02
 tempFile 03
 tempFile 03

 tempFile 01
 tempFile 02
 tempFile 03
 tempFile 03

 tempFile 01
 tempFile 02
 tempFile 03
 tempFile 03

 tempFile 01
 tempFile 02
 tempFile 03
 tempFile 03
File2
File3
 @type ABCDF
File4
 @type ABCDF
File5
```

---

### Expected output of the script

```
File1
 @type ABCDF #---Insert 'tempfile' content below First occurrence '@type ABCDF'
 tempFile 01
 tempFile 02
 tempFile 03
 tempFile 03
File2
File3
 @type ABCDF
File4
 @type ABCDF
File5
```

Comment: Related, see [How to parse XML in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/893585/608639), [How to parse XML using shellscript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4680143/608639) and friends.

Comment: I want to just insert the content of tempFile into File1 at specific position. For your convenience,  I have changed the  content of tempFile and File1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with `awk` fairly easily using a variable to serve as a flag to only write the contents of `tempfile` once after the first occurrence of `"@type ABCDF"`. The approach is simple, you output every line with the first `{print}` rule, then if `/@type ABCDF/ && n`, you loop with `getline` reading each line from `tempfile` and outputting it. When done outputting the file, you simply set `n=0` and it will skip all the other occurrences of `"@type ABCDF"` in the file, e.g.

```
awk -vn=1 '{print}; /@type ABCDF/ && n{while (getline <"tempfile") print;n=0}' file1
```

**Example Input file1**

```
$ cat file1
File1
 @type ABCDF #---Insert 'tempfile' content below First occurrence '@type ABCDF'
File2
File3
 @type ABCDF
File4
 @type ABCDF
File5
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ awk -vn=1 '{print}; /@type ABCDF/ && n{while (getline <"tempfile") print;n=0}' file1
File1
 @type ABCDF #---Insert 'tempfile' content below First occurrence '@type ABCDF'
tempFile 01
tempFile 02
tempFile 03
tempFile 03
File2
File3
 @type ABCDF
File4
 @type ABCDF
File5
```

You can redirect the output to a temporary file and then replace the original to emulate an *in-place* addition of the lines.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
touch result                                                          #Intermediate file
lineNumber=$(grep -n -m 1 '@type ABCD' File1 | awk -F':'  '{print $1}' | head -1)
head -n $lineNumber File1 >> result                                   #First two lines
cat tempfile >> result                                                #Append your tempfile
sed -n "3,`wc -l File1 | awk ' { print $1}'`p" File1 >> result        #Rest of File1
mv result File1                                                       #Rename it to File1
```

Comment: Why use `sed` for the last part? `tail -n +$(lineNumber)` or so?

Comment: In bash there are often many ways to get a job done.This is why I love it.