# How to extract XML data in shell script?

Tags: xml, shell

I'm looing for a way to extract my data from the below XML file structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>**MyClassController**</members>
        <name>ApexClass</name>
    </types>
    <version>51.0</version>
</Package>
```

The expected result is MyClassController. What is the command I should use and can you please give me a sample?

Comment: I'd use `xmlstarlet sel -t -v '//_:members[text()]'  input.xml`

Comment: @Shawn, thank you. your suggestion work for me as well.

Comment: What if you want to do it in a bash file on CI/CD and not able to install startlet or other third party?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer may help
[How to parse XML using shellscript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4680143/how-to-parse-xml-using-shellscript)

Easier way is, if you know exactly what tag you want you can do

```sh
rg -o '<members>(.*)</members>' -r '$1' < your.xml
```

rg is ripgrep (https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep), a great tool but you need to install

Comment: Thank you @Leo Liu , the code works for my case.